# What is the difference between fff and ms in datetime?

Tags: c#, datetime

What is the difference between fff and ms in datetime?

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
string s1 = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
string s2 = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss-ms");
```

The output will be as below:

> 2018-12-03 14:28:23.357
>
> 2018-12-03-02-28-23-2823

You see that 357 is different from 2823. What is the reason? Thanks.

Edit: Thanks all of you. I wonder how ms came out of my mind. Maybe I mix it with Oracle. Haha.

Comment: Isn't that because `m` is minute and `s` is second, and there isn't a combination `ms`?

Comment: There's one `f` for every level of precision of milliseconds. `ss` is for two digit seconds (i.e. `1` will be displayed as `01`) and `s` is for one digit seconds. Same with `m`, only for minutes. It's all documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: `.fff` is milliseconds, `m` is minute and `s` is seconds, so in the first one you will get 357 which represent the milliseconds, and in the second one you get 2823, which if you can see, are 28 23 which correspond to you minute and seconds before the dash('-')

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't any `ms` format-key to formatting `DateTime` in **C#**. The `m` stands for *minute* and the `s` stands for *second*. So, `ms` is just a combination of minute and second along together. For *formatting milliseconds* in `DateTime` the pattern uses `f` and `F`. What you did actually, was putting a `m` beside a `s`. So you got `28` beside `23` which results `2823`.

For more information, see the doc: [How to: Display Milliseconds in Date and Time Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-display-milliseconds-in-date-and-time-values)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?view=netframework-4.7.2

There is no `ms` specifier; what you have is the concatenation of the `m` (minutes, 28 in this case) and the `s` specifier (seconds, 23), hence 2823.

Answer (score 1):

You can investigate the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

```
"fff" - The milliseconds in a date and time value.
```

`ms` is combination minutes and seconds.